# how can I symlink my home folder from another drive?

Tags: symbolic-link

More specifically, I want to have the user folder for my home account another disk that has more space, but keep my other smaller accounts on my ssd. I was able to copy my user folder to another disk, but now I need to link it to the home folder on my ssd, I want it accessible from a normal boot, and please don't tell me that what I did was not the best thing, I just want an answer.  How do I get it to create a link that goes from /home/username to /extra-home/username and is recognised by the system when loading the user folders?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Remember that your permissions will need to be the same.  In addition to symlink, on more recent distros and filesystems, as root you can also use bind-mount:

```bsh
mkdir /home/username 
mount --bind --verbose /extra-home/username /home/username
```

This is useful for allowing access "through" the `/home` directory to subdirs via daemons that are otherwise configured to avoid pathing through symlinks (apache, ftpd, etc.).

You have to remember (or init script) to bind upon restarts, of course.

Comment: I wasn't aware that symlinks could create such issues. How do such daemons treat `/var/run/`?

Comment: The servers are designed to restrict access to the local filesystem, to avoid compromising the system.  You can think of this as "things allowed to remote users".  They need not restrict themselves from accessing /var/run (typically at startup/shutdown) as "things allowed to this process".  See Apache's FollowSymLinks directive for an example of how to allow the served filesystem to traverse symlinks, if desired.

Comment: can we also expand /bin and /lib in the same way (can be useful in small filesystem) ?

Comment: Does your system need `/bin` and `/lib` at initialization (i.e. before you can run the `mount` command)?  If so, then you cannot employ this strategy.

Comment: Adding info here, as I had to search for it, once that is done to add init in /etc/fstab here is the form. When using the method Joe described `mount --bind --verbose /extra-home/username /home/username`, the line in `/etc/fstab` would be `/extra-home/username /home/username none defaults,bind 0 0`

Comment: What should the `/etc/passwd` entry for such a user list as its home-directory in a setup like this;`/extra-home/username` or `/home/username` still?

Answer (score 11):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/107208/linux-can-a-home-directory-be-symlinked) question on Super User this is possible.

You can create a symbolic link using:

```
ln -s /extra-home/username /home/username
```

If it doesn't work for some reason you can just delete the symbolic link, move the directory back and reboot your computer.

Comment: If it's a simple folder you have to start with /media/{hardrive_name}/{your folder} I have just tried this on a debian server and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I would try this:

While logged in as a different user, in a root shell (e.g. `sudo -i`), copy over the contents of `/home/username` to `/extra-home/username` and make sure the new location is owned by `username`:

```
# cp -p /home/username /extra-home/
# chown username:username /extra-home/username
```

Move the original `/home/username/` directory to a safe place:

```
# mv /home/username /root/
```

Create the symlink:

```
# ln -s /extra-home/username /home/username
```

Verify it's working as expected by opening another terminal window and running `su`:

```
$ sudo su username
```

If everything looks good, at least from the terminal (contents of `/home/username/` appear as expected), then log out and log back in (I'm assuming you're on Ubuntu desktop) and it *should* be working normally. However, if it isn't, just delete the symlink and move the archived home folder back to its original location.

Comment: Old answer, but +1 for clear instructions with a fallback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My experience on this is: it never doesn't work well with symlinks. Permissions, user services and so on sometime doesn't follow or work with symlinks: so you may get **sudo** doesn't working, user configuration app doesn't working correctly and so on...

The best solution, in my humble opinion, is to put all the homes on the same partition and mount it on /home. If you have more than a spare disk you can:

- to buy a RAID card
- put all the disks you want to use for users home on the RAID card.
- Configure RAID as JBOD (disks will sum the space). During PC boot, RAID cards start a BIOS to configure drives before the OS starts. There are other RAID configurations, but it depends on your needs.
- Now you have like a new single huge disk just for /home
- `sudo copy -pr` the /home folder on the new drive
- edit /ect/fstab to mount the drive on /home

This way you can grow the /home size incredibly any time you need, just adding another drive to the RAID.